# Unable to get cookies in blazor web assembly from web api

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

Please help me I don't know what can be wrong, I've been trying to find something for hours...

I want to have a user login component on the cookie in blazor. I have set the cookies and implemented logged out but I am unable to check that the cookie exist or not in web api code to get information from the cookies to blazor client app.

In web api this is my program.cs

[image]

In blazor web assembly app this is my program.cs

[image]

Now this is my getcurrentuser in which request.cookies["abc"] works if I consumed it from web api but if I use blazor web assembly to call the web api it doesn't work it is returning null. how can i make this

[image]

Updated:

[image]

My web api project where i am adding cookie

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your configuration information, I guess your verification process should be as follows:

> `Blazor WebAssembly` requests the `API` for user authentication by
> sending the user credentials to `API`.
>
> For valid credentials, `API` generates auth cookie and sends it to the
> client application.
>
> So after successful authentication of every request from `Blazor WebAssembly` to `API`, the auth cookie will be attached to every
> subsequent request to make the request as authenticated.

Just from the code you provided, I have no way of knowing how you are setting the cookies, but here is an example: [BlazorWasmSocialLoginCookieAuth](https://github.com/Naveen512/BlazorWasmSocialLoginCookieAuth), I think it will be helpful for you.

In fact, this example is not complete (the author may have some problems when uploading), you need to create a database and table (Database: `BwasmAllCookieAuth` Table: `User`), and then add a default account in the table, and you need to add the corresponding connection string in `appsetting.json`. I've tested it and it works fine after adding it.

Your `GetCurrentUser` method is equivalent to the [`UserProfileAsync`](https://github.com/Naveen512/BlazorWasmSocialLoginCookieAuth/blob/master/CookieApi/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L69) in the example, I read the Cookie in it, it can be obtained:

```
var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];
```

Here is the explanation corresponding to this example, which may help you understand it faster: [Blazor WebAssembly Cookie Authentication[.NET 6]](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/04/blazorwasm-cookie-series-part-1-blazor-webassembly-cookie-authentication.html).

Comment: var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["hhh"]; it is returning null. i checked it is present there

Comment: Hi @maztt, where did you add `Cookies["hhh"]`?

Comment: i am adding it In the  web api

Comment: I am adding this from my client application

Comment: Hi @maztt, Whether `Cookies["hhh"]` is set by `Response.Cookies.Append()`? It should be a cookie you added manually, right? However, the image you provided does not contain relevant information. I tested and your problem not appeared. Maybe we have some different configurations that make it impossible to reproduce. Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: yes it is a cookie and i added it by httpcontext.signinasync .cookies are not set by Response.Cookies.Append()

Comment: Secondly https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2022/04/blazorwasm-cookie-series-part-1-blazor-webassembly-cookie-authentication.html this worked for me . so my question here is is claim based authentication is the way to go? i was hoping to use Response.Cookies.Append() like approach to get my cookies as i used it before without web api?

Comment: are you using it in var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Cookies"];. will it work with correct cofiguation in client and web api scenario?

Comment: My web api and blazor assembly configuration is given above. the code by which i am adding a cookie is also in loginasync above